# C++ - DFS code error

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

I tried to implement this algorithm but there's some logical error. The algorithm is given below.

```
DFS(G)

1.  for each vertex u ∈ G.V

2.     u.color = WHITE
3.     u.pi = NIL

4.  time = 0

5.  for each vertex u ∈ G.V
6.     if u.color == WHITE
7.        DFS-VISIT(G,u)


DFS-VISIT(G,u)

1.  time = time + 1
2.  u.d = time
3.  u.color = GRAY

4.  for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]
5.     if v.color == WHITE
6.        v.pi = u

7.        DFS-VISIT(G,v)

8.  u.color = BLACK
9.  time = time + 1
10.  u.f = time
```

**Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define WHITE 0
#define GRAY 1
#define BLACK 2
#define SIZE 100

int Time;

int adj[SIZE][SIZE];
int color[SIZE];
int parent[SIZE];

int d[SIZE];

void dfs_Visit(int G, int u)
{
    Time++;
    d[u] = Time;
    color[u] = GRAY;

    for(int i = 0; i < G; i++)
    {
        if(color[i] == WHITE)
        {
            parent[i] = u;
            dfs_Visit(G, i);
        }
    }
    color[u] = BLACK;

    Time++;
    cout << u << " ";
}


void dfs(int G)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < G; i++)
    {
        color[i] = WHITE;
        parent[i]=NULL;
    }

    Time=0;

    cout << "DFS is ";
    for(int i = 0; i < G; i++)
    {
        if(color[i] == WHITE)
        {
            dfs_Visit(G, i);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int vertex;
    int edge;
    cout << "VERTEX & Edge  : ";
    cin >> vertex >> edge;

    cout << "Vertex is : " << vertex <<endl;
    cout << "Edge is : " << edge <<endl;

    int node1, node2;
    for(int i = 0; i < edge; i++)
    {
        cout << "EDGE " << i << ": ";
        cin >> node1 >> node2;
        adj[node1][node2] = 1;
        adj[node2][node1] = 1;

    }
    dfs(vertex);
}
```

[**Output picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krvcj.png)

**Inputs:**

<kbd>VERTEX & Edge  : 4 5

Vertex is : 4

Edge is : 5

EDGE 0: 0 1

EDGE 1: 1 2

EDGE 2: 2 0

EDGE 3: 0 3

EDGE 4: 2 4</kbd>

**Output:**

```
DFS is 3 2 1 0
```

And the accepted result is `2 1 3 0`

Comment: *CAN ANYONE HELP ME OUT?* Your caps lock is on.

Comment: *BUT THERE IS SOME ERROR !* And what error would that be?

Comment: I cannot find it out ! sir .. the result is incorrect !

Comment: So what is the result you expect and what is the result you see?

Comment: `Time = Time++;` is incorrect, either `Time++;` or `Time = Time+1;`

Comment: I Followed this algorithm and i dont get the real ans.

Comment: How many times? What is the real answer, what is the answer you see instead? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I forgot about that and i changed it but the result is same !

Comment: Sir i Add my code result and the result i wanted ..

Comment: 3210 is the output of my code and the result i wanted is  2 1 3 0.. sir please help me out ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't coded DFS-VISIT step 4 correctly

Step 4 says `for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]` but your code says `for(int i=0; i<G; i++)`. Those aren't the same thing at all. You should only visit the adjacent vertexes.

In fact if you look at your code you never use `adj` at all. That can't be right.